# How to remove first string element stored in array in a queue without STL?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, queue

I have a code to remove the first element of a string array.But its deleting the last entered element.How do I delete the first element in the queue without using STL and how do I reset the queue to empty.Here is my class declaration as Queue.h file and QueueImpl.h as its a template file.You got to include all the functions implemented in Queueimpl.h file and then include it in main.I have successfully deleted the element from the queue and I can see that when printing queue but while searching it, the deleted element still exists why is it that

```
     Queue.h
        template <class Type>
        class Queue
        {

        private:
            int counter;
            int Queue_size;
            Type* Contents;
            int Front, Back;
            int items_in_queue = 0;

        public:
            Queue(int queue_size = 10);
            ~Queue();
            bool Empty() const;
            bool Full() const;
            void Remove();
            int Add(const Type& new_element);
            int QueueSize();
            Type front();
            int search(string &element,int numElm);
            void clear();
            bool IsDigitsOnly(string &strn);

        };

        #endif

         QueueImpl.h

                  #pragma once
#ifndef QUEUETEMPLATE_H
#define QUEUETEMPLATE_H
#include<string>
#include "queue.h"
const int MAX_SIZE = 10;
// Constructor
int counter = 0;



template<class Type>
Queue<Type>::Queue(int queue_size) :
    Queue_size(queue_size),
    Contents(new Type[queue_size + 1]),
    Front(0), Back(0)
{}

// Destructor
template<class Type>
Queue<Type> :: ~Queue()
{
    delete[] Contents;
}

// Tests
template<class Type>
void Queue<Type>::clear()
{
    while (!Empty()) {
        Front = Back = -1;


            }





}


template<class Type>
bool Queue<Type>::Empty() const
{
    return (Front == Back) ? true : false;
}
template<class Type>
bool Queue<Type>::Full() const
{
    return ((1 + Back) % (Queue_size + 1) == Front) ? true : false;
}

/
}








#endif
```

Comment: Please past the complete example. This piece of your code is not compilable, the function Remove declaration is invalid.

Comment: Please store the template file in .h extension and include them in main

Comment: Why is there an `e` at the bottom of the file? Also, your code formatting is horrendous.

Comment: sorry,i changed it now...

Comment: This does not compile. Post a complete program all in one piece, not .h files and fragments that we must assemble. Read this: [MCVE]

Comment: my main program is 650 lines of code hence i didnt post it.Please see now

Comment: Did you look at the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help page? You should create a new program, not paste your codes.

Comment: Some of them are saying the code is incomplete and some of them are saying code is too long...whom should i listen to?

Comment: Please do not deface your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now it is enough. I do not want to criticize your code style. It would be better if you would demonstrate an example of usage. Without it I assume Type is std::string. I remove `<Type>` for simplifications. Let start.

1. `IsDigitsOnly` does not relate to your class. It is better to move it into a separate function.
2. Why you need `queue_size + 1` of elements in the array `Contents` if `queue_size` is desired?
3. The constructor `Queue::Queue` initializes an empty queue object, zeros `Front` and `Back`. It should be done in `Queue::clear`: `Front = Back = 0` instead of `Front = Back = -1`.
4. Simply `return Front == Back` instead of `return (Front == Back) ? true : false`.
5. `Queue::Full` would be identical to `Queue::Empty`. They both should check `counter`.
6. `Queue::Remove`: the condition `if (Front == Back)` is always `false`, since the same condition is in `if (Empty())`. The final `else` is right, since you are using correct `Queue_size`. You must `counter--` there.
7. In `Queue::Add` the erroneous `Queue_size + 1` is used.
8. `Queue::search` does not use `Front` and `Back` therefore it is wrong. See below.

Let stop here. I hope you are able to move forward yourself.

*New to the 5 and 8.*

```
template<class Type>
bool Queue<Type>::Empty() const
{
    return counter == 0;
}

template<class Type>
bool Queue<Type>::Full() const
{
    return counter == Queue_size;
}

template<class Type>
int Queue<Type>::search(const Type& element, int numElm)
{
    if (numElm < Front || numElm >= Back)
        return -1;
    // Used as a subscript to search array
    for (int index = numElm; index != Back; index = (index + 1) % Queue_size)
    {
        if (Contents[index] == element) // If the value is found 
            return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.but how do I clear the contents of the queue?

Comment: You do not need clear the contents. Cells starting from `Back` and before `Front` are assumed free. If you wish to be more accurate with the memory usage then in `Queue::Empty` assign `Type()` to cell pointed by `Front` before its increment.

Comment: Thanks.I have successfully deleted the element from the queue and i can see that when printing queue but while searching it ,the deleted element still exists why is it that

Comment: It is definitely because you do not use `Front` and `Back` there. Please think and do it right. I am not going to do whole work for you. Especially you do not vote for my answer, that  fully covered your initial answer.

Comment: Sorry for that.I am busy with my assignments.Please help me in this case.Its only a minor thing.Please help me search in the dynamic queue

Comment: Should not we have to decrement the index?